# In Azure API Management, how can you load-balance and failover on 3 different backends?

Tags: azure-api-management

I am figuring out a way for API management to failover over multiple backends.

The question is very similar to the ff:

- [How can you use Azure API Management policy to load balance calls to a backend service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497599/how-can-you-use-azure-api-management-policy-to-load-balance-calls-to-a-backend-s)
- [Simulating a failover with Azure API Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809619/simulating-a-failover-with-azure-api-management)

The difference is that instead of two backends, I have three. i.e.

1. If backend1 fails, try backend2
2. If backend2 still fails, try backend3
3. If backend3 still fails, try backend1 again.

My best guess here is to somehow get the `<retry>` **counter** if possible. Something like:

```xml
<backend>
    <retry condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 500" count="9" interval="10" first-fast-retry="true">
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(int.Parse(context.RetryCount) % 3 == 0)">
                <set-backend-service backend-id="backend2" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(int.Parse(context.RetryCount) % 3 == 1)">
                <set-backend-service backend-id="backend3" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-backend-service backend-id="backend1" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>

        <forward-request />
    </retry>
</backend>
```

But this isn't working, as there's no such thing as `context.RetryCount`, is there such a variable? Or any other suggestions?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to round-robin load balance the backend in addition to this retry. But I'll take any solution for now.

Comment: Update: declared a custom counter variable which I increment in the `<retry>`, but would still love to know if there's a better way.

Comment: A not-so-nice effect is that the counter starts at `0` at every call. Meaning every call to this API starts with **backend1**. I'm not sure if there's a way for it to remember the previous backend service that was used.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, posting here as it may help someone. Also, if someone here knows a better way, please share.

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cache-lookup-value key="backend-counter" variable-name="backend-counter" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(!context.Variables.ContainsKey("backend-counter"))">
                <set-variable name="backend-counter" value="0" />
                <cache-store-value key="backend-counter" value="0" duration="100" />
            </when>
        </choose>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(int.Parse((string)context.Variables["backend-counter"]) == 0)">
                <set-backend-service backend-id="backend1" />
                <set-variable name="backend-counter" value="1" />
                <cache-store-value key="backend-counter" value="1" duration="100" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(int.Parse((string)context.Variables["backend-counter"]) == 1)">
                <set-backend-service backend-id="backend2" />
                <set-variable name="backend-counter" value="2" />
                <cache-store-value key="backend-counter" value="2" duration="100" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-backend-service backend-id="backend3" />
                <set-variable name="backend-counter" value="0" />
                <cache-store-value key="backend-counter" value="0" duration="100" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <retry condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 500 || context.Response.StatusCode >= 400)" count="6" interval="10" first-fast-retry="true">
            <choose>
                <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 500 || context.Response.StatusCode >= 400)">
                    <when condition="@(int.Parse((string)context.Variables["backend-counter"]) == 0)">
                        <set-backend-service backend-id="backend1" />
                        <set-variable name="backend-counter" value="1" />
                        <cache-store-value key="backend-counter" value="1" duration="100" />
                    </when>
                    <when condition="@(int.Parse((string)context.Variables["backend-counter"]) == 1)">
                        <set-backend-service backend-id="backend2" />
                        <set-variable name="backend-counter" value="2" />
                        <cache-store-value key="backend-counter" value="2" duration="100" />
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <set-backend-service backend-id="backend3" />
                        <set-variable name="backend-counter" value="0" />
                        <cache-store-value key="backend-counter" value="0" duration="100" />
                    </otherwise>
                </when>
            </choose>
            <forward-request buffer-request-body="true" />
        </retry>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <!-- Uncomment for debugging, this outputs the next backend-counter in the JSON response body. -->
        <!--
        <set-body>@{ 
            JObject body = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>(); 
            body.Add(new JProperty("backend-counter", ((string)context.Variables["backend-counter"])));
            return body.ToString(); 
        }</set-body>
        -->
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```